# KeyEvent.ACTION_UP only works when I use computer keyboard but not works in android virtual keyboard

Tags: java, android

I'd like to search words in a webview. So in android emulator when I type in edittext something using my computer keyboard as I type the search will start finding words. But when I use android keyboard in emulator or real device nothing happens, will not search the words.

```
if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) || ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)))
            {
                myWebView.findAllAsync(findBox.getText().toString());
```

Any ideas how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically if you are using an edit text box

```
EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (editable.length() != 0) {
        // save the content here
    }
}
});
```

for further reading [read this](https://mobikul.com/android-applying-text-watcher-edittext/)

use this with your edit text field, basically, it will listen for any text changes other than key up action! cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I can put `myWebView.findAllAsync(findBox.getText().toString());` inside onTextChanged and that is it?

Comment: yes indeed! you can pass the text like that from using any of the implemented methods. for your scenario, afterTextChanged is the most suitable one.